# R Program- i would like generate the random sample but with specified lower and upper limit. <x=abs(rnorm(100,mean=10,sd=5))

Tags: r

I am using R software for learning.

i tried generating random sample but i do not know how to get the sample between ranges.

i would like generate the random sample with mean 10 and standard deviation 5 but data with specified lower and upper limit. for example car mileage, ranges between 14 to 20 miles.

Comment: From what distribution? If you're looking for the truncated normal, there's an R package for that: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/truncnorm/truncnorm.pdf

Comment: It's easy to generate a uniform distribution with a particular range using `runif`. Obtaining a specific SD is more difficult.

Comment: Having a range between 14 and 20, it would be impossible to have a mean of 10 when your lowest possible value is 14. Additionally it's impossible to have a standard deviation of 5 when your range is only 6. You may need to review some basic statistical material on random sampling and distributions.

Comment: Well, if you are a Bayesian and you mean _posterior mean_, then this is certainly possible, with some strong prior. :)

Comment: You might want to do further searching on "rejection sampling".

Answer (score 1):

Interpreting the question liberally, you can generate a distribution with mean 10 and sd of 5 and then simply pick out the values between 14 and 20.

```
rnorm(1000000,mean=10,sd=5) -> x
x[x>14 & x <20][1:100] -> x
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlike some of the commenters I did not see that you wnated the resulting set of values to ahve a mean of 10, but rather wanted to know how to restrict the sample to a particular range in the "right side" of the (sample) distribution:

```
> x=abs(rnorm(100,mean=10,sd=5))

> Hmisc::describe(x)
x 
      n missing  unique    Mean     .05     .10     .25     .50     .75     .90     .95 
    100       0     100   10.01   2.713   3.830   6.995   9.899  13.338  15.890  17.244 

lowest :  0.2297  1.2789  1.4875  2.1591  2.7105
highest: 17.4245 18.2214 18.5216 20.6713 29.7004 
> x[ x >10 & x < 14 ]
 [1] 12.18180 12.20234 10.88162 13.29551 11.93855 12.88514 10.16698 11.59605 10.49250
[10] 11.87572 12.39030 11.94950 13.46728 13.82126 10.83314 12.43298 10.14287 11.55421
[19] 10.30776 12.24819 13.55493 10.49318 10.40018 12.51552 10.63401 10.15365 11.16643
[28] 11.01404

> x[ x >14 & x < 20 ]
 [1] 15.67082 14.23257 15.32423 17.23473 16.49950 17.19964 15.98334 15.87908 17.42446
[10] 18.22140 14.20300 14.40036 15.82410 15.15962 18.52156 14.55390 15.36474 14.37368
[19] 16.90896 14.61357
```